# Add RabbitMQ distributed tracing to Zipkin

Tags: rabbitmq, zipkin

We have been playing around with Brave(Java implementation of Zipkin) and successfully added tracing for REST and database calls. We would like to also add RabbitMQ to the tracing and would like some thoughts from anyone who may have had similar experiences that they could share.

We have tried to find some stuff online but can't seem to find an interceptor we could add to our rabbit implementation. Can you recommend anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ask for a feature is using github issues.

To add a new transport such as RabbitMQ, you'd have to affect Brave (reporter) and Zipkin (collector)

https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues
https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues